# Paging with in a time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

Hi is it possible to fire pageindex changing event of a gridview with in a time interval?

Actually i tried with some code but it is showing page event args e not exist.  How do i call this event in a timer tick in asp.net c# application?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASPX Markup

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="3">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer1_Tick1">
            </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Code-Behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Data();
        }
    }
    void Data()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("No");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.PageCount == GridView1.PageIndex)
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
        GridView1.PageIndex++;
        Data();
    }
```